# Why does my Bluetooth Mouse Stops working if two Devices connected to my Windows Surface 3?

Tags: windows, mouse, bluetooth, microsoft-surface

I've got a bluetooth mouse, [HDE Ergonomic Bluetooth Wireless Optical Laser Mouse for Android Tablets](http://smile.amazon.com/HDE-Ergonomic-Bluetooth-Wireless-Optical/dp/B00LC8SLLE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1464895472&sr=8-1&keywords=hde+bluetooth+mouse), that works fine when it is the only Bluetooth device connected to a Windows Surface 3.

Once I connect my Bluetooth head phones than the mouse cursor will freeze and only update once every few seconds. The headphones play music just fine no matter the number of devices connected.  The mouse is using the generic drivers since I can't find specific drivers for it.

Both devices work fine when connected to an android phone.

Comment: Are all updated installed on the Surface 3 (both firmware and software)? I am wondering if the "***for Android Tablets***" has anything to do with the issue you are having. Amazon notes state "*Mouse is compatible with Android OS versions 3.1 or newer*" and "*You may need a USB dongle or other Bluetooth adapter in order to pair this mouse with some PCs or laptops; please consult your manufacturer for compatibility before purchase*"

Comment: All the updates that Windows Update has pestered me about have been installed.